# Is there a way to use a variable Type as a Type?

Tags: c#

I have a Dictionary from which I get a specific type (for example myType =int) and I want to use it to cast a comboBox item into it but I get the error : "My type is a variable but it is used as a Type". Is there a way I can use my variable myType as a Type in this case?

```
// Dictionary<string, Type> ComboBoxItemsNames

Type myType = ComboBoxItemsNames.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == itemChanged.Text).Value;

var selectedItem = (myType)itemChanged.ComboBoxItem;
```

Comment: Methinks you do not yet understand the concept of a _static type system_ (like C# has)...

Comment: What would be the point of doing this? `selectedItem` will be an instance of what ever `ComboBoxItem` is but the compiler doesn't know the actual value and uses object.

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: there is `var selectedItem = Convert.ChangeType(itemChanged.ComboBoxItem, mytype);` but selectedItem will still be of type object (for the compiler) - `Convert.ChangeType` is only usefull for converting one type to another, eg. int to long  https://dotnetfiddle.net/E0GScH

Comment: The type that I want to cast the item to is not a simple type rather a type that I have created myself and then I use the properties of that class for the code further on

Comment: `then I use the properties of that class for the code further on` but how should the compiler know which type it is? it could be anything. The compiler has no idea, what type you are expecting. if you know the types you are dealing with just use `if (itemChanged.ComboBoxItem is Foo foo) { Console.WriteLine(foo.Bar); }` with this I have declared a variable of the type `Foo` and the compiler knows what to do.

Comment: @RandRandom There is no legitimate use for `Convert.ChangeType` at all, though. The entire `Convert` class should be removed from .NET, imo (and its Base64 methods moved elsewhere).